# DataBinding to a DataGrid Not Working

Tags: .net, wpf

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Person> lista = new List<Person>();
    lista.Add(new Person(1, "Joao", 50.0f));
    lista.Add(new Person(2, "Maria", 150.0f));

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = lista;
  }

  public class Person
  {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public float salary;

    public Person(int id, string name, float salary)
    {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.salary = salary;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Apart from your formatting there is nothing directly wrong. What happens and how is it different from what you expected?

Comment: this code generate 2 lines to a datagrid, but they are empty

Comment: Does your grid have columns defined? That match the properties?

Comment: I added binding, and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Binding is generally to *properties*, not *fields*:

```
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public decimal Salary {get;set;}

public Person(int id, string name, decimal salary)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    Salary = salary;
}
```

note also - `Salary` should certainly be a `decimal` (not a `float`).

If you find you can't create new rows of `Person` records, try adding a parameterless constructor:

```
public Person() { Name = ""; }
```

Comment: I added this and worked. Thank you.
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Canvas.Left="143" Canvas.Top="66" Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salary}" Header="Salary"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>